# Disable/Prevent search callback when inserting new row with jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, sorting, search, datatables, jquery-callback

### **Background:**

I have a Datatable that I am creating like this in JS:

```
let mytable = $('#myTableId').DataTable();
```

Then later on in my code, I am programmatically adding 5 rows to this datatable like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
    mytable.row.add(someVectorValuedFunction(i)).draw(false);
}
```

### **Problem:**

Every time a row is inserted into the datatable 'mytable', the datatable sorting function is called. The sorting function runs is O(n) - ie, it iterates through every row and decides whether to show that row or hide it. Therefore inserting n rows into 'mytable' has an effective worst case complexity of O(n^2). The exact complexity is something like n(n-1) becomes of the running aggregation of sort cycles.

### **Constraint:**

**I need to be able to sort the table at some point.** This means that whatever solution I find must be consistent with the table's ability to sort **OR** I need to be able to disable and then enable sorting on the table.

### **Question:**

***How do I prevent the sorting function from being called every time a row is inserted into a jQuery Datatable?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the draw(false) -> draw('page').
This should stop the draw function from reordering and resorting according to the documentation.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: Wow that was fairly simple. Thank you!